# Using a dockerfile and/or docker-compose is there a way to run commands after a docker image launches?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to configure a database container (PostgreSQL) and I want to configure some database settings by running SQL commands against the started instance. The RUN command in a dockerfile runs BEFORE the database launches.

I guess I could create a script to first stand up the docker instances then push out the configuration, but that's neither portable nor elegant.

Is there a way to somehow configure RUN commands or similar to run AFTER the container instance starts?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be:

1. Create a bash script containing the startup commands you want to run inside your container
2. Copy that script into the docker image with a `COPY` command
3. Change the `RUN` command in the `Dockerfile` to run your script on startup, instead of calling `postgres` directly
4. Ensure your script calls `postgres` (like the original `RUN` command did) before your configuration commands

You might need your script to run postgres in the background:

```bash
# Run postgres, but in the background, so we can execute more commands
postgres ... & pg_pid="$!"

# Your configuration commands here
...

# Tell bash not to exit until postgres does
wait $pg_pid
```

However, I don't know whether docker will shut down `postgres` gently in this case.  (It might just kill the shell.)

---

You can also override the default `RUN` command by specifying your startup command with [`docker run ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28490909/99777)